# How to get an alert when page loads for whether local storage retrieval worked or not

Tags: javascript, local-storage, alert

I have part of a code that moves an array into local storage, and now I am trying to retrieve it from local storage. When the page loads, I am trying to implement an alert that lets the user know whether the array has been retrieved successfully or not.

html

```
<input text="text" value="Resturant Name" id="input5"/>;
<input text="text" value="Item Name" id="input6"/>;
<input text="text" value="Item price" id="input7"/>;
   <br>
<input text wrap ="text" value="Jimmy John's" id="input1"/>
<input text wrap="text" value="Billy Club, Turkey Tom, Totally Tuna, The 
Veggie" id="input2"/>
<input text="text" value="$8.09, $7.99, $9.49, $6.99 " id="input8"/>
<br>
<input text="text" value="Red Robins" id="input3"/>
<input text="text" value="Fish and Chips, Clucks and Shrimp, Salmon, 
Cheeseburger" id="input4"/>
<input text="text" value="$9.99, $13.29, $12.79, $8.19" id="input9"/>
<br>
<input text="text" value="Bob Evans" id="input10"/>
<input text="text" value="Homestead Breakfast, Fruitiful Farmer, Chicken 
Tenders, Meatloaf" id="input11"/>
<input text="text" value="$7.99, $8.99, $11.49, $12.99" id="input12"/>
<br>
<input text="text" value="The Brown Jug" id="input13"/>
<input text="text" value="Italian Club, Tuna Salad, Parm Sandwhich, 
Potato Skin" id="input14"/>
<input text="text" value="$9.99, $7.99, $8.99, $8.50" id="input15"/>


javascript 

function add() {
var els = [
    [
        document.getElementById('input5'),
        document.getElementById('input6'),
        document.getElementById('input7')
    ],
    extern double a[3][5];   
   [
        document.getElementById('input1'),
        document.getElementById('input3'),
          document.getElementById('input10')
    ]
];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    result[result.length] = parseInt(els[0][i].value) - parseInt(els[1] 
   [i].value);
}

alert(result.join(' '));


 console.log("FoodItems");
    localStorage.setItem("FoodItems", JSON.stringify(FoodItems));

 window.onload= GetFoodItems = 
    JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem('FoodItems')));
      alert("FoodItems " + FoodItems + "\nStatus: " + status);

  }
```

Comment: You can grab local storage , and check if it avaible, if yes show your alert and remove your local storage, sorry I can't give you example I'm on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener to the window `load` event, then retrieve the item from local storage.

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => { 
    const ret = localStorage.getItem("myItem");
    if(!ret) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: I added some text to your answer. Code only answers are almost always bad, please provide a description and some context if you can.